# Finding a free space within current bounds of view on iOS

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, uiimageview, subview

I have an infinite scrollview in which I add images as the user scrolls. Those images have varying heights and I've been trying to come up with the best way of finding a clear space inside the current bounds of the view that would allow me to add the image view.

Is there anything built-in that would make my search more efficient?

The problem is I want the images to be sort of glued to one another with no blank space between them. Making the search through 320x480 pixels tends to be quite a CPU hog. Does anyone know an efficient method to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're scrolling this thing vertically (you mentioned varying image *heights*).

There's nothing built in to `UIScrollView` that will do this for you. You'll have to track your `UIImageView` subviews manually. You could simply maintain the max y coordinate occupied by you images as you add them.

You might consider using `UITableView` instead, and implementing a *very* customized `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your delegate. You would probably need to do something special with the actual cells as well, but it would seem to make your job a little easier.

Also, for what it's worth, you might find a way to avoid making your solution *infinite*. Be careful about your memory footprint! iOS will shut your app off if things get out of hand.

UPDATE

Ok, now I understand what you're going for. I had imagined that you were presenting photographs or something rectangular like that. If I were trying to cover a scroll view with `UILeaf`s (wah wah) I would take a statistical approach. I would 'paint' leaves randomly along horizontal/vertical strips as the user scrolls. Perhaps that's what you're doing already? Whatever you're doing I think it looks good.

Now I guess that the reason you're asking is to prevent the little random white spots that show through - is that right? If I may suggest a different solution: try to color the background of your scroll view to something earthy that looks good if it shows through here and there.

Also, it occurred to me that you could use a larger template image -- something that already has a nice distribution of leaves -- with transparency all along the outside outline of the leaves but nowhere else. Then you could tile these, but with overlap, so that the alpha just shows through to the leaves below. You could have a number of these images so that it doesn't look obvious. This would take away all of the uncertainty and make your retiling very efficient.

Also, consider learning about [CoreAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514) ([CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) in particular) and [CoreGraphics/Quartz 2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1) ). Proper use of these libraries will probably yield great improvements in rendering speed.

UPDATE 2:

If your images are all 150px wide, then split your scrollview into columns and add/remove based on those (as discussed in chat).

Good luck!

Comment: My scrollview has the ability to scroll in any direction, so I couldn't really use a tableview for that. As for its infinity, it doesn't extend infinitely, it only moves the images currently on the screen to the opposite direction of the scroll and when there are more than 20 subviews, I remove the very first one that's been added and so forth.

Comment: If it scrolls both ways, then I don't understand the concept you're after with regard to the layout of these images within the scroll view. Can you add some clarity there? Maybe a screenshot of what you already have?

Comment: Here's an example: http://twitpic.com/8slalg - so the whole area that I've added leaves on top of has different image views on it. Now, the image that I've not put leaves on should be added immediately under the one above it and to the right of the one on its left. My question is, how do I find the exact (x,y) where the image needs to go without wasting too much CPU time?

Comment: Yowsa! That's a nice pic, I really like the effect. But a few different things come to mind, and I will need a moment to add them to my response...

Comment: Great - I look forward to hearing them :-) Could you perhaps email me at appetizer.inc [AT] gmail.com so we can talk more about this issue? Thanks :-)

Comment: It's not the leafs that are the images. The leafs I only used to cover the images in my app :) I want the space between the image with the "Girls..." text and the image to its left (there's a grey bit between the two images) to disappear. So the end result would be the two images next to each other with no space between them.

Comment: Are the leaves part of the app at all? Anyway, enough on the leaves I guess. Are your images different sizes entirely? Do you have to have that gray background at all? Can you just make that white?

Comment: Join me if you please in iOS Chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad)

Comment: No, the leafs are not part of the app. The images have a standard width of 150. The height is that which differs. I cannot make the background white as not all images have white edges, and there needs to be a sense of the images being one next to the other rather than far apart.